# Unable to print PNG files using Java Print Services (Everything else works fine)

Tags: java, printing

I am using the Java print services to print a PNG file, however it is sending erroneous output to the printer. What actually gets printed (when I use a PNG) is some text saying:

```
ERROR: /syntaxerror in --%ztokenexec_continue--
                Operand stack:
                              --nostringval-
```

There seems to be some more text, but that is kind of lost out of the page margins. I am setting the DocFlavor to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG` and the specified file is actually an `InputStream` (Just changing the DoccFlavor to `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF` and using a pdf file works).

I have also tried it with different PNG files, but the problem persists. For what its worth, even PostScript seems to be working.

The errors that are being printed look quite similar to the `gd` (or ImageMagick?) errors. So, my best assumption right now is that the conversion from PNG -> PS is failing.

The code is as follows:

```
PrintService printService = this.getPrintService("My printer name");

final Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(document, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG, null);
final DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
```

Here, `getPrintService` fetches a print service and is fetching a valid one. As for the `document`, here is how I get it:

```
File pngFile = new File("/home/rprabhu/temp/myprintfile.png");
FileInputStream document = new FileInputStream(pngFile);
```

I have no clue why it is going wrong, and I don't see any errors being output to the console as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try loading the png in a small swing application. In fact ImageIO.read would already do. Or .png is a lie, try DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE. Try another png.

Comment: I've tried another PNG (many actually, generated by a variety of programs). .png is definitely not a lie. Tried AUTOSENSE; didn't work

Comment: Then DocFlavor.URL.PNG with `new URL("file:/...")` will probably not do too. As hack solution you can read the image with ImageIO.read and wite it with ImageIO.write to a ByteArrayOutputStream to a jpg, and use DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.JPEG. Check the file attributes, maybe copy the file out of the temp directory.

Answer (score 1):

Printing is always a messy business – inevitably so, because you have to worry about tedious details such as the size of a page, the margin sizes, and how many pages you're going to need for your output. As you might expect, the process for printing an image is different from printing text and you may also have the added complication of several printers with different capabilities being available, so with certain types of documents you need to select an appropriate printer.

Please see below links :

http://vineetreynolds.wordpress.com/2005/12/12/silent-print-a-pdf-print-pdf-programmatically/
http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-print-service-frustrations.html